# Highly unusual ASP.net Session variable persistence

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I've got a really really strange ASP.net intermittent session persistence problem. First some facts:

Environment:

- F5 Load Balancer with sticky sessions enabled:
- Web Servers: 2 *
  Windows Server 2008 R2,
- .net Framework Version: 2.0.50727, IIS7,
- Database Server: SQL Server 2008 R2
- Session Protocol: ASP.net InProc sessions, timeout set to 20mins, cookieless=false
- CMS: Ektron CMS
  400.net

Ok on with the problem.

We have some custom VB.net session values which get set in our website for a shopping cart. from time to time SOME of these variables seem to lose persistence. I say some because the main session remains persistent. I think the main culprit is this fellow:

```
Shared Sub New()
    ' If the cart is not in the session, create one and put it there
    ' Otherwise, get it from the session
    If HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") Is Nothing Then
        Instance = New ShoppingCart()
        Instance.Items = New List(Of CartItem)
        HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") = Instance
    Else
        Instance = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("ASPNETShoppingCart"), ShoppingCart)
    End If

End Sub
```

Even when this session object remains persistent, it doesn't show up when I run a trace:

e.g.

my other sessions variables like Session("userId") show up in a trace while I NEVER see a value for Session("ASPNETShoppingCart") - which I thought was strange - perhaps this is because it is an object as opposed to a string?

I've ruled out issues with the load balancer by bypassing it directly and calling the code directly on the server.

I know the full session is not being destroyed when the issue occurs because I'm still logged in and other session values appear on screen - but my shopping cart values do not.

Has anyone any idea as to what might cause something like this? Is there any way of protecting a session variable or at least being notified if it changes state so I can trace what's causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it is strange that "some" variables get lost and some don't.

Maybe you have some sort of "fallback" mechanism that recreates the "UserID" (from an authentication cookie, for example) and the same doesn't happen for other objects.

In general, I'd avoid using InProc session state at all costs because whenever the asp.net Worker process get's recycled -and this can happen at any time-, everything in the Session will be lost. Since you use sticky sessions, my suggestion is that you switch to `OutOfProcess` mode using a local `StateServer`. You can read [more here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)It's very simple to configure; just a change in the Web.config and making sure that the ASP.NET State service is started on the server.

The only caveat is that all your objects need to be Serializable but if you are not storing something exotic in Session, all you need to do is decorate your objects with the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: Hi Icarus, thanks for the feedback. I have indeed considered switching my protocol to OutofProcess and also storing them in the DB - but before I take that 'nuclear' option I was hoping to pinpoint why just this session object is losing persistence. The strange thing is that I can't recreate this on another mirror of the production server. Same code, same db, etc. so I'm thinking it's some environment variable like an IIS setting, a windows service that's interfering with sessions, some antivirus or firewall differences (you get the idea!)

Comment: Good that you have a mirror of Production but you also need to be able to reproduce the same load conditions as your production env. I hope you don't have an antivirus on a production server. I would be very mad at someone that does something like this.

Comment: so would I - I don't control the sys admin elements of the main production environment myself so I can't rule anything out!